# Remainder of $100^{10k} \text{ by } 13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to find out the remainder of the Euclidean division of $100^{10k}$  by $13, k \in \mathbb{N}$

Could anyone support me with some hints

Comment: updated "rest" -> "remainder"

Comment: $$10^3\equiv-1\pmod{13}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first lets calculate the remainder for $100^k, k\in\mathbb{R}$

for k=1, R=1

for k=2, R=9

for k=3, R=3

for k=4, R=1

As you can see, the remainder only depends on k mod 3.(mod returns the remainder) 
So what about $100^{10k}$? Let's calculate 10k mod 3.(since k is an integer, I'll start with k=1)

for k = 1, R = 1

for k = 2, R = 2

for k = 3, R = 0

for k = 4, R = 1

...

So when K mod 3 = 0, then 10k mod 3 = 0, so the remainder will be 1

So when K mod 3 = 1, then 10k mod 3 = 1, so the remainder will be 9

So when K mod 3 = 2, then 10k mod 3 = 2, so the remainder will be 3

Comment: $100 = 7\cdot 13 +9$ so the reminder is 9 not 1

Comment: We have different remainders for different values of K. For k = 1, 4, 7, 10, ... the remainder is 9

Comment: but for $k = 1$

Answer (score 1):

You have to discard multiples of $13$.  See that $100 = 7\cdot 13 +9$, so you can just compute the remainder of $9^{10k} = 3^{20k}$.  Then observe that $27$ is $2\cdot 13+1$ so that $3^{20k} = ((3^3)^6\cdot 3^2)^k = (27^6 \cdot 9)^k.$
Throwing out the multiples of $13$ from the $27$'s gives us $9^k$ to find the remainder of.  The answer depends on $k$.  I'd look at it as $3^{2k}$ and find out what remainders are possible raising $3$ to an even power.  This is cyclic and there are only 3 possibilities, depending on whether $k$ has the shape $3n$, $3n+1$ or $3n+2$ (again, look for the $27$'s.)